# Safari calls my controller twice when loading the JSP

Tags: model-view-controller, safari

Doesn't happen in Firefox. I deactivated the extensions. didnt help. Version is 5.0.1.
Any ideas?

Comment: perhaps a HEAD request that checks whether the client cache is still valid?

Comment: perhaps a HEAD request to check whether the client cache is still valid?

Comment: Empty IMG element maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Leppie (above) was right...for me at least.  I had a `<img src=""/>` in my JSP that caused Safari to load the page twice...which in turned called saveToken twice in my Struts Action and subsequently caused isTokenValid to return false when it shouldn't have.

The simple solution is to fix the IMG element by referencing an image in the src tag.

Enjoy,
Randy